# Retaining confidence intervals with dwplot in R while setting x axis limits in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I'm trying to use the ggplot2 and dotwhisker packages in R to display coefficient estimates from a model. One of my covariates has very wide confidence intervals, so the scale of the x-axis is very large. When I set the x-axis limits narrower than the CIs, the CI bars disappear from the plot. Is there a way to retain the CIs, even though they will be cropped?

For example, I produce figure 1:

```
data(mtcars)
mtest <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = mtcars)
dwplot(mtest)
```

[image: figure 1 - with confidence intervals but wide axis range]

When I try to set the axis limits I lose the CI, as in figure 2:

```
dwplot(mtest) +  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-4, 1))
```

[image: figure 2 - with a narrower axis scale but without the confidence intervals]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (much) less demanding way to accomplish this than hand-drawing your own whiskers is with `coord_cartesian()`:

```r
library(dotwhisker)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

data(mtcars)
mtest <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = mtcars)
dwplot(mtest) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-4, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a more elegant solution, but a workaround is to inspect the confidence interval and manually draw on the whiskers.

```
data(mtcars)
mtest <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = mtcars)
summary(mtest)
confint(mtest)
dwplot(mtest) +  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(-4, 1))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=-4, xend=-1.649972, y=1, yend = 1), 
  color = "salmon")
```

This generates the following plot:
[image: Figure with CIs manually drawn on]